# Float without overriding padding

Tags: html, css

I'm making a site that has 3 different `span` that sits next to each other by using a `float:left` parameter. But this messes up the `padding` I have on the wrapper the two elements are contained in.
How can I make them sit next to each other without messing with the padding?

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ee792emc/2)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: red;
}

.box-A {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

.box-A {
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Not working but aligned</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-A">
    Lorem
  </div>
  <div class="box-A">
    Ipsum
    <br> Ipsum
    <br> Ipsum
    <br> Ipsum
    <br>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Working, but not aligned</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-B">
    Lorem
    <br> Lorem
    <Br>
  </div>
  <div class="box-B">
    Ipsum
    <br> Ipsum
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions to be fixed the issue.

1. Using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`and [remove the spaces which is occured by](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) `inline-block`
2. Adding [`clearfix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) to wrapper

Comment: That did it! Thank you. This will become useful later on!

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Not working but aligned</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-A">
    Lorem
  </div>
  <div class="box-A">
    Ipsum<br>
    Ipsum<br>
    Ipsum<br>
    Ipsum<br>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box-A {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

.box-A {
  width: 49%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try This maybe helpful, in wrapper class set Display:inline-Block

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` on `wrapper`

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;/*Add This Property*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your css, I hope this should be work.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: red;
}
.box-A {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

.box-A {
  width: 49%;
}

.wrapper:after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```